# Gauss's lemma: More than a stepping stone on the way to proving $R[x]$ is a UFD when $R$ is?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, factoring, irreducible-polynomials, unique-factorization-domains

I'm reviewing my abstract algebra a bit. Currently looking at UFDs. In this context, Gauss's lemma (or part of it, at least) says that the product of two primitive polynomials over a UFD is primitive.

It seems to me that Gauss's lemma follows pretty easily from the Theorem  that $R[x]$ is a UFD when $R$ is. However, this is a bit logically backwards, since I think Gauss's lemma is a sort of a preliminary step towards proving exactly that theorem?

> **Argument:** Let $R$ be a UFD. Suppose that $p(x)q(x)$ is not primitve, where $p(x),q(x) \in R[x]$. Thus, there must be some nonunit element of $R$ dividing $p(x)q(x)$. It follows that there is an irreducible $r$ of $R$ which divides $p(x)q(x)$. Now it is easy to see that an irreducible element of $R$ is still an irreducible element of $R[x]$ (degrees add, so you can't factor a constant into anything but constants). Since $R[x]$ is a UFD, its irreducibles are also prime, so $r$ is a prime element of $R[x]$. Then, from $r|p(x)q(x)$, we get that $r|p(x)$ or $r|q(x)$, so one of $p(x)$ or $q(x)$ is not primitive.

My question is sort of a philisophical one:

> **Question:** Is it correct to think of Gauss's lemma as just a partial result which is then superseded by the Theorem: "$R$ a UFD implies $R[x]$ a UFD", or am I somehow missing out on something here? In other words, is this roughly how you think of Gauss's Lemma, or do you view it as a useful result in its own right?

Comment: Gauss lemma generalizes to arbitrary commutative rings by considering a polynomial primitive off it's coefficients (as principal ideals) generates $1$.

Comment: Being UFD is something more related to Noetherianess (guarantees a factorization) and the property that every irreducible is prime (although, some UFD may not be Noetherian).

Comment: @user40276: Thanks for the comment! Any idea what that generalized version of Gauss's lemma could be used for?

Comment: No. The unique useful applications that I can think is in the case of Dedekind domains (that are already UFD's)

Answer (score 2):

There seem to be two different approaches to thinking about Gauss' Lemma.

The first approach, the one you're talking about, does not *quite* require unique factorization, but holds for arbitrary [GCD domains](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GCD_domain), where factorizations into irreducibles may not exist at all.  [The proof](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_lemma_%28polynomial%29#A_proof_valid_over_any_GCD_domain) resembles the classical proof using a notion of "content".

But there is a second approach that avoids this entirely—that doesn't work for all UFDs, but works for $\mathbb{Z}$—which is to use the fact that $\mathbb{Z}$ is a [Bézout domain] to show that the coefficients of primitive polynomials generate the unit ideal, then using [only basic commutative ring theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_lemma_%28polynomial%29#A_variation.2C_valid_over_arbitrary_commutative_rings).